# Trying to upload song to firebase and to app fails with exception

Tags: android, arrays, firebase, error-handling

I'm trying to make a music app and the app crashes whenever i try to upload a song to it, the error is:

```
2021-05-25 04:51:02.446 24439-24439/com.example.msctry E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.msctry, PID: 24439
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=101, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/msf:7900 flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.example.msctry/com.example.msctry.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5097)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5138)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2147)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7814)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
        at com.example.msctry.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:112)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8292)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5090)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5138) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2147) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7814) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
```

At first I thought I just didn't give internal storage permession so i did but it still happens, this is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.msctry">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MscTry">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and this is the main activity file:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    TextView TextimageView;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    Uri audiouri;
    StorageReference mstorage;
    StorageTask mUploadTask;
    DatabaseReference reference;
    String songsCategory;
    MediaMetadataRetriever mediaMetadataRetriever;
    byte[] art;
    String title1,artist1,album_art1="",duration1;
    TextView title,artist,durations,album,dataa;
    ImageView album_art;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextimageView=findViewById(R.id.tvuploadsongfileselected);
        progressBar=findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
        title=findViewById(R.id.title);
        artist=findViewById(R.id.artist);
        durations=findViewById(R.id.duration);
        album=findViewById(R.id.album);
        dataa=findViewById(R.id.data);
        album_art=findViewById(R.id.img);
        mediaMetadataRetriever=new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        reference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("songs");
        mstorage= FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("songs");
        Spinner spinner=findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        List<String> categories=new ArrayList<>();
        categories.add("Jogging Songs");
        categories.add("Swimming Exercise Songs");
        categories.add("Aerobic Songs");
        categories.add("Walking Songs");
        categories.add("Biking Songs");
        categories.add("Physical Therapy Songs");
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,categories);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    }


    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        songsCategory=parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Selected"+songsCategory, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
    public  void openAudioFiles(View v){
        Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        i.setType("audio/*");
        startActivityForResult(i,101);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode==101&& resultCode==RESULT_OK && data.getData()!=null){
            audiouri=data.getData();
            String fileNames=getFileName(audiouri);
            TextimageView.setText(fileNames);
            mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(this,audiouri);
            art=mediaMetadataRetriever.getEmbeddedPicture();
            Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(art,0,art.length);
            album_art.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            album.setText(mediaMetadataRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM));
            artist.setText(mediaMetadataRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST));
            dataa.setText(mediaMetadataRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_GENRE));
            durations.setText(mediaMetadataRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION));
            title.setText(mediaMetadataRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE));
            artist1=mediaMetadataRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST);
            title1=mediaMetadataRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE);
            duration1=mediaMetadataRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);


        }
    }
    private  String getFileName(Uri uri){
        String result=null;
        if(uri.getScheme().equals("content")){
            Cursor cursor=getContentResolver().query(uri,null,null,null,null);
            try {
                if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    result = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));

                }
            }finally {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
        if(result==null){
            result=uri.getPath();
            int cut=result.lastIndexOf('/');
            if(cut!=-1){
                result=result.substring(cut+1);
            }
        }
        return  result;
    }
    public  void uploadFileToFirebase(View v){
        if(TextimageView.equals("No file Selected")){
            Toast.makeText(this, "please select an image!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }else{
            if(mUploadTask!=null&& mUploadTask.isInProgress()){
                Toast.makeText(this, "song upload is in progress !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }else{
                uploadFiles();
            }
        }
    }

    private void uploadFiles() {
        if(audiouri!=null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Song Is Uploading Please Wait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            final StorageReference storageReference = mstorage.child(System.currentTimeMillis() + "." + getfileextension(audiouri));
            mUploadTask = storageReference.putFile(audiouri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    storageReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                            UploadSong uploadSong = new UploadSong(songsCategory, title1, artist1, album_art1, duration1, uri.toString());
                            String uploadId = reference.push().getKey();
                            reference.child(uploadId).setValue(uploadSong);


                        }
                    });

                }
            }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onProgress(@NonNull UploadTask.TaskSnapshot snapshot) {
                    double progress = (100.0 * snapshot.getBytesTransferred() / snapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                    progressBar.setProgress((int) progress);

                }
            });
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "No file Selected to Upload", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }




    }
    private  String getfileextension(Uri audiouri){
        ContentResolver contentResolver=getContentResolver();
        MimeTypeMap mimeTypeMap=MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        return mimeTypeMap.getExtensionFromMimeType(contentResolver.getType(audiouri));

    }
}
```

the error happens in the line:

```
Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(art,0,art.length);
```

for some reason they cant get the length of the song I'm trying to upload, and I don't get why, i tried to run the app on a different phone and when i selected the song from some music player the app crashed and when i did from audio it didnt crash, but it doesnt work at all in my actual phone

Comment: Maybe there isnt an embedded picture for that song file?

Comment: Make sure to call `length` when `art` is not null, otherwise you'll get NPE.

Comment: @AlexMamo how ?

Comment: @lyncx I'm not sure it's a file from youtube to mp3 converter

Comment: Check against nullity.

Comment: @AlexMamo if(art!=null){ return art.lenght}?

Comment: Yes. Do you still get the error?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes I do

Answer (score 1):

You're close but this should work

```
art=mediaMetadataRetriever.getEmbeddedPicture();
if(art != null){
Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(art,0,art.length);
album_art.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

You just need to check if art is null or not as some song may not have an album art.

P.S. This should work for saving it, when you're retrieving your data you will have to check it for null as well